Transform a number column to time
I have column like with numbers and i want to transform it in time or add ":" between the numbers.
Have any grel or python formula that i can use ?
I appreciate any help.



how it is




1104


030


940






how i espect




11:04


00:30


09:40




what type are they? int? strings?

They are as int.

so the second one is 30 not 030?

They are as string. My bad.

You can use this GREL expression:
splitByLengths(value + "0000"[0,4-value.length()], 2, 2)[0] + ":" + splitByLengths(value + "0000"[0,4-value.length()], 2, 2)[1]

First, padding is applied to the right to make the string four characters long using value + "0000"[0,4-value.length()]. Then this new string is passed to the splitByLengths function to extract the first two and last two characters, which are then joined with a colon (:) in between.
